How to get Shiny Chat's response to display formatted math equations?
I am trying to get this example app to output formated math equations. The shiny chat tutorial here suggests a custom response display, but I am unable to get the suggested @chat.transform_assistant_response to modify the formating.
I used the code below as is:
@chat.transform_assistant_response
def _(content: str) -> ui.HTML:
    return ui.markdown(content)

adding transform_assistant=True to  chat.messages() but I saw no change of the formating of the response.
I need help getting formated math equations of the reponse.
As is, submitting for example 'solve x^2-4=0' will return something like this:


A possibility is that you add MathJax and set it up accordingly. And then one important point is that after a message is appended, we send a typeset queue such that the newly inserted content is rendered correctly.
Here it is implemented that we can send a message and use inlineMath (using $) and displayMath (using $$) to render the input mathematically.
Extending the output using @chat.transform_assistant_response is possible, however, in the below example it is not needed.

from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, ui

mathjax = ui.head_content(
    ui.tags.script(
        src="https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
    ),
    ui.tags.script("""if (window.MathJax) {
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax: {
                inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\\\(", "\\\\)"]],
                displayMath: [["$$", "$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"]],
                processEscapes: true
            },
            config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
            jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
            extensions: ["MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"]
        });
        $(function() {
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("typeset", function(message) {
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
            });
        });
        }
        """),
)

app_ui = ui.page_fillable(
    mathjax,
    ui.panel_title("Hello $\LaTeX$ Shiny Chat"),
    ui.chat_ui("chat"),  
    fillable_mobile=True,
)

def server(input: Inputs, output: Outputs, session: Session):
    # Create a chat instance and display it
    chat = ui.Chat(id="chat")

    # Define a callback to run when the user submits a message
    @chat.on_user_submit  
    async def _():
        # Simply echo the user's input back to them
        await chat.append_message(f"""Input rendered as math: <br> 
                                  {chat.user_input()}
                                  """) 
        # trigger MathJax typeset 
        await session.send_custom_message("typeset", {"msg": "dummy"})

app = App(app_ui, server)


Thank you for this answer; what I am looking for is to have a chatGPT like output, combining text and nicely formatted math equations. Your answer formats all texts into math format.

Is your goal that e.g. If 'Text $a$' is entered as a message, then 'Text' appears as text and 'a' is rendered as math?

Yes, that is the goal.

Thank you for the clarification, please see my updated answer.

I cannot tell what is wrong but the solution here doesn't work when I use it to chat with openai, for example. Is there a way you can get your solution to work with the example I provided? You may try to request a solution for x^2-4=0 to see what it returns. Thank you.

Did you instruct the model to output equations in LaTeX / between dollar signs or something similar before? Otherwise this can't be recognized as math.

Your solution is about right. It has two things to fix. (1) It doesn't recognize inline math equations. (2) The latest querry will not output the latex math format; but when I run a new querry, the previous querry has the display math formula well formatted. I will fibble around with it, hopefully I am able to fix these two issues. Thank you for your help.

Replacing  inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\\\(", "\\\\)"]] with inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]] solved the inline math formatting issue on my side. The remaining issue is that the formatting is applied on the previous querry, not the latest. I am not sure why that is the case.

Thank you! Concerning the remaining problem I think that the rendering (typeset) isn't triggered at the correct time point, this is the MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]); above. However, I would need a minimal example or something else in order to investigate this, and I don't have an API key ... Above this is received by session.send_custom_message("typeset", {"msg": "dummy"}) and from what you write I think the trigger is not working if the message is displayed first inside the chat?

Can I link up with you and screenshare what I have. my contact is sbikienga@gmail.com, if that is fine with you. I am currently available.

I've written down your mail, but today I won't have time, we can try it later. For this problem here: The only thing what you most probably need is an event if a new message is displayed inside the chat. Maybe you can check chat.messages(), this is a reactive value containing the chat messages. If you observe for a change here and then trigger session.send_custom_message("typeset", {"msg": "dummy"}), it might go in the right direction?

Thank you for all your help. I will keep you updated.

I reposted a new question here to fully explain the remaining issue.

Thank you! So now where we have a follow-up question, how do you would like to proceed here? This question is still open and I would like to close it.

Please do. Thank you
